# How to use Phone verification without creating new user

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, firebase-authentication

Hi I'm using react native now.
I've been facing this problem

**I want to use Phone verification without creating new user.**

But I can't find what I want to.
I tried using npm @react-native-firebase/auth and firebase auth
I couldn't find it.
I'd really appreciate your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I want to use Phone verification without create new user.

Phone number verification is built into Firebase as a way of creating/verifying a user. These is no way to use Firebase's phone number verification without creating a user account in Firebase Authentication.

Answer (score 1):

Firebase provides support for locally testing phone numbers. For local testing to work, you must have ensured your local machine SHA1 debug key was added whilst creating your application on the Firebase Console.

**After successfully creating** a user with an email and password (see Authentication/Usage/Email/Password sign-in), use the **verifyPhoneNumber** method to send a verification code to a user's phone number and if the user enters the correct code, link the phone number to the authenticated user's account.

```
{...}
import auth from '@react-native-firebase/auth';

export default function PhoneVerification() {
     {...}

     // Handle the verify phone button press
       async function verifyPhoneNumber(phoneNumber) {
         const confirmation = await auth().verifyPhoneNumber(phoneNumber);
         console.log(confirmation);
       }

     // Handle confirm code button press
       async function confirmCode() {
         try {
           const credential = auth.PhoneAuthProvider.credential(confirm.verificationId, code);
           let userData = await auth().currentUser.linkWithCredential(credential);
           setUser(userData.user);
         } catch (error) {
           if (error.code == 'auth/invalid-verification-code') {
             console.log('Invalid code.');
           } else {
             console.log('Account linking error');
           }
         }
       }


     {...}

     <Button
      title="Verify Phone Number"
      onPress={() => verifyPhoneNumber('ENTER A VALID TESTING OR REAL PHONE NUMBER HERE')}
    />


     <Button title="Confirm Code" onPress={() => confirmCode()} />

     {...}
}
```

Enter phone number (e.g. +44 7444 555666) and a test code (e.g. 123456).
For more datails https://rnfirebase.io/auth/phone-auth

Comment: Take care to handle Android's auto verification carefully. If an Android device verifies the SMS code in the background by itself, `confirmation` will end up being `{ "code": null, "error": null, "state": "verified", "verificationId": null }`. In this case, you need to immediately build the `auth.PhoneAuthProvider.credential(null, null)` and link it to the signed in user. See [react-native-firebase#1962](https://github.com/invertase/react-native-firebase/issues/1962) and [react-native-firebase#2895](https://github.com/invertase/react-native-firebase/issues/2895) for details.